# Collapsing multiple panel-body under one heading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a collapsible panel with bootstrap, where only certain parts are to slide closed. So in the code below I want the panel-body-1 and panel-body-2 to animate closed when the header is clicked. Panel-teaser-1 and panel-teaser-2 are to remain open. Is this possible? Thank you.

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
           href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Panel-Header-1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-teaser panel-body" >
      Panel-Teaser-1
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
         role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel-Body-1
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="panel-teaser panel-body" >
      Panel-Teaser-2
    </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
         role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel-Body-2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using Bootstrap version 3 (what you have looks a lot like the example from the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse)).

If you use a `<button>` tag instead of an `<a>` tag, then you can simply comma-separate multiple ids for the elements that you want to collapse in the `data-target` attribute. (Notice that I used a bootstrap class to style the button to appear as an anchor tag)

```
<h4 class="panel-title">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" 
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne,#collapseTwo">
      Panel-Header-1
  </button>
</h4>
```

A working example is on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux53Lu32/5/)

Comment: Yes, that is brilliant. Thank you so much!